# JMS clients should only be java based?

Tags: java, jms, activemq-classic

Per [wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_Message_Service) link JMS is a Java Message Oriented Middleware (MOM) API[1](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_Message_Service) for sending messages between two or more clients

Question :- Is it mandatory that client(Producer/Consumer) should be implemented in java or client can be implemented in any technology  like dot-net/c++ ? Can browser also be a client  provided it sends the message expected by java MOM

**Update :-**

JMS can use variety of protocols to send/receive the message. For example :- If I consider the case of ActiveMQ  it support number of protocols given at [active MQ protocols](http://activemq.apache.org/protocols.html) where as  default protocol is AMQP.

So mine understanding with default protocol AMQP, Dot-net/C++ can be client  but not browser(as it communicates over http only).

But if i configure the ActiveMQ to use Rest protocol probably anyone(browser/Dot-Net/C++) can be client . Is that correct ?

Comment: ActiveMQ might have a JMS adapter, but it's wider than JMS.  I know Rabbit MQ can be used that way in Cloud Foundry.  You asked about JMS.  Your new question is broader.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

JMS is an API specification. It's not mandatory to implement the API specification in Java, it can be done in other languages too. Many of the JMS implementations provide .NET, C++/C etc implementations for JMS. For example IBM MQ provides JMS API implementation in .NET and C/C++ languages and it's called XMS.

Comment: I believe You mean IBM MQ clients can be in any language but IBM MQ broker itself is implemented in java

Comment: No, I didn't mean that. Both clients and broker can be implemented in any language. IBM MQ queue manager ( or broker) is implemented in C language.

Comment: Thanks. Then J in JMS makes me confused as both clients and broker are not bound to java ?

Comment: Just out of curiosity that if `Both clients and broker can be implemented in any language` then any specific reason why it is called java messaging service ?

Comment: I think it's because JMS specification was developed by the Java community under the Java community process.